# Easy way to get a readable date from a long (timestamp) in scala

Tags: scala, apache

My question is simple

If I do:

```
var start = System.currentTimeMillis
```

I get:

```
start: Long = 1542717303659
```

How should I do to get a string looking to something readable for a human eye?:

ex: "20/11/2018 13:30:10"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `java.time` library like:

```
  val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
  formatter.format(LocalDateTime.now)
```

If you only have the timestamp, this solution gets a bit more complex:

```
formatter.format(LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(System.currentTimeMillis()), ZoneId.of("UTC")))
```

Then I would take `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` :

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(System.currentTimeMillis())
```

To get back to the Timestamp:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse( "02/12/2012 12:23:44" ).getTime
```

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to do the opposite? create a timestamp long with a string date?

Answer (score 3):

Don't overthink it: nothing wrong with just `new Date(start).toString`

Comment: Thank you!! :-) But this give me a date, I really need a time with it to evaluate how long a scipt take to run. :-)

Comment: Did you try it? :) (it gives you time too). But if all you need is evaluate what the script took, you are probably better off with `Long` to begin with. Just subtract start from the end, and you get the number of milliseconds.

Comment: Hi yes I did the substract but I wanted to print the datetime too. But I try your solution and get only a date...

Comment: scala> var start = System.currentTimeMillis
start: Long = 1542805880478

scala> new Date(start).toString
res23: String = 2018-11-21

Comment: Hmm ... Wrong `Date`? Try `new java.util.Date(1542805880478l).toString`

Comment: yes if I do this, it works. I do not understand what wasn't working... Thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use java.time library and get it in readable format as below one-liner.

```
scala>  java.time.LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(System.currentTimeMillis/1000,0,java.time.ZoneOffset.UTC)
res31: java.time.LocalDateTime = 2018-11-21T18:37:49

scala>
```

I'm just diving the Milliseconds by 1000, so that we get EpochSecond.

For getting it back,

```
scala> java.time.LocalDateTime.parse("2018-11-21T18:41:29").toEpochSecond(java.time.ZoneOffset.UTC)
res40: Long = 1542825689

scala>
```